# Correlation length in a 3d Ising slab with one dimension much smaller than the other two

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, correlation-functions, ising-model

Suppose I have a 3d Ising model on a cubic lattice, but one of its dimensions is much smaller than the other two. That is, I have an $L$ by $L$ by $L'$ slab with $L' << L$; in particular, $L'$ will be comparable to $\log(L)$.

I'm imagining periodic boundary conditions throughout. Suppose that $T_{2d}<T<T_{3d}$, so the temperature is below the usual $3d$ Ising critical temperature but above the usual $2d$ Ising critical temperature.

Within this temperature regime, how does the correlation length depend on $L'$? I'm interested in the correlation length along one of the "long" directions $L$.

I suspect that it might depend strongly on $L'$ as $e^{f(T) L'}$ or stronger for $L' = O(\log(L))$, though it might ceiling out once $L'$ is too big. Here $f(T)$ is some function of temperature that should be fairly regular when the temperature is strictly between $T_{2d}$ and $T_{3d}$ (though it might behave singularly at $T_{2d}$ and $T_{3d}$. In particular, I want to rule out that at small $L'$ the correlation length grows faster than $e^{f(T) L'}$, such as ruling out a growth like $e^{f(T) (L')^2}$.